# introducir una funcion en otro spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy creando mi aplicacion en un spreadsheet(libro1), y desde este libro1 por codigo,creo otro spreadasheet(libro2).

Quiero que crear una funcion (funcion1) en el libro1, que cree una funcion (funcion2) en el libro2 y programar un disparador en el libro2, para cuando este se actualice, automaticamente se lance la funcion2 sobre el libro2.

Libro2 es un spreadsheet que se crea y se destruye dinamicamente desde Libro1,es decir, desde el propio codigo del libro1 se genera un nuevo spreadsheet (libro2), los usuarios hacen anotan cosas en el durante un tiempo, semanas, meses, y pasado ese tiempo el libro se elimina. Pero necesito hacer que en libro2, se ejecuten automaticamente algunas funciones cuando cada vez que un alguien anota algo en el libro, bien porque se abre manualmente, bien porque recibe respuestas nuevas de un formulario.

Buscando documentacion encontre un codigo que adapte lo mejor que entendí:

```
function configuraDisparador(idLlibre,funcio) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idLlibre);
  var scriptId = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var resource = {
    functionDefinition: funcio,  
  };
  var request = {  
    resource: resource, devMode: true, 
  };
  var response = 
  spreadsheet.DeveloperMetadata.update(request, idLlibre);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcio)
     .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
     .onChange()
     .create(); 
}
```

Entiendo que spreadsheet.DeveloperMetadata es lo que crea el codigo en libro2 pero me da fallo y no encuentro documentación que explieque como usarlo o que me confirme que spreadsheet.DeveloperMetadata sirva o no para lo que quiero.
¿Podeis ayudarme?
Gràcies.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has investigado y qué has intentado? ¿Cuál es el problema con lo que has intentado o qué no entiendes de lo que has investigado? Por otra parte, ¿qué es lo que justifica tener un libro que se cree y se destruya dinámicamente? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Buscando documentacion encontre un codigo que adapte:

Comment: Convendría que agregues ese código a la pregunta y que indiques qué errores o dificultades tienes con él.

Comment: Segun leo en los post.. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/get?hl=es-419 parece ser una funciones de la "API REST" no del entorno de google app script. Es decir, esa funcion "DeveloperMetadata" esta disponible para ejecutar desde una API.